# WMI Win32_PhysicalMedia SerialNumber is sometimes hexadecimal and sometimes in reversed byte order

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, wmi, serial-number

I am using WMI with C++ to get the physical disk serial number.

On Windows 7 64bit, I get a string with the serial number.

While when running the same application on a Windows XP 64bit machine I get a hexadecimal string with each char's values reversed.

I have noticed 3 different behaviours so far:

1. Windows 7 64bit
   String in correct order as expect
2. Windows XP 64bit(Machine 1)
   Hexadecimal string, reversed byte order
3. Windows XP 64bit(Machine 2)
   String in reversed byte order

I have used wbemtest.exe and have confirmed that these results are coming from WMI, not my own code.

When I use DeviceIOControl and get the SMART information I always get the serial number as a hexadecimal string with reversed byte order.

Is this expected behavior and how does one handle this?

Comment: I can't help but I've just come across a similar issue. A string is returned in XP/Admin account and Windows 7/Run as Admin. However, hex is returned in Windows 7/Run as normal. I wonder if Machine 1 is non-admin XP?

Comment: It gets more bizarre. Apparently under Vista, when executed under a standard account, non-hex is returned (as expected), but it is jumbled up. See here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623282/win32-physicalmedia-returns-incorrect-serial-number-on-vista-or-higher-when-run-as-standard-user#details