# Win32_PhysicalMedia SerialNumber sometimes in wrong order

Tags: c++, wmi

Referring to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) i modify abit the code so i can retrieve HDD Serial Number

```
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);
..
..<other code here>
..
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
```

I convert vtProp.bstrVal to std::wstring and do a reverse string, the reason i have to reverse the result from vtProp.bstrVal is because i found that some of the computer i use to retrieve serial number is in wrong order

For example:
Computer 1 return serial: **W[space]-DXW1M6EC01056**, i have to do a reverse string to make it **[space]WD-WXM1E60C0165** which is correct after compare with label on the HDD

but when i test with
Computer 2 return serial: **WD-WXM1E60C0165** (i use the same code, it actually return correctly when i check with the serial label on the HDD)
if my code do a reverse string, it will become **W[space]-DXW1M6EC01056**

I check with both computer, it is Little-Endian, i do not know whether it has something to do with Endianness or not.

Is there anything making the return result in different order?
HDD maker/brand?
I run the program in Windows XP Pro for all test result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WMI HDD Serial Number Transposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989338/wmi-hdd-serial-number-transposed)

Comment: it looks like have peoples facing similar problems, i would like to find a way to know when and why sometimes it is in wrong order compare to the label/sticker on HDD.

The return Serial Number i use is for licensing purpose, if the machine/computer always return a wrong order, it may or may not cause any problem when my licensing mechanism compare the HDD serial.

Comment: One of the linked articles has a working solution.  You can't depend on WMI.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft knows about it:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623282/win32-physicalmedia-returns-incorrect-serial-number-on-vista-or-higher-when-run-as-standard-user

So do other Stack Overlow users:

[WMI Win32_PhysicalMedia SerialNumber is sometimes hexadecimal and sometimes in reversed byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903463/wmi-win32-physicalmedia-serialnumber-is-sometimes-hexadecimal-and-sometimes-in-r)

[WMI HDD Serial Number Transposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989338/wmi-hdd-serial-number-transposed)